# Hibernate: What is the use of center table in mapping relationships other than fetching data collectively?

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I am mapping different tables for an online doctor appointment system. In order to map different associations e.g. one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many etc I need a center tables for some of the entities. My question is why do I need the center table other than that it fetches all the data automatically when I get an object. For example

I have following tables 
chamber, weekdays, time_slots and in order to show relation between them i use tables chamber_day and day_slot as center tables between. Now I only populate data in the first thee tables, the next three tables are automatically filled with the help of association in the hbm files. Now when I am making an appointment I need to store the information chamber id, weekdays id and timeslot id in appointment table. My question is that does this design specify as per the requirements or needs any change.

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be stated more clearly, perhaps with examples of code that you are attempting, but if I understand what you are saying...

You should only need center tables when doing many-to-many joins. If you are ending up with these extra tables when doing one-many/many-one joins, that is not technically needed for any reason I can think of.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Completely agreeing with Andrew. Centre tables are only needed for many to many relationships(even if you go through cardinality rules in database). For all the other relationships foreign key can be made available in one of the tables without any data redundancy.